# Close Reason Editor: Customize your off-topic close reasons

Tags: script, closing

### About

The Close Reason Editor allows you edit the off-topic close reasons which are normally editable only by the site moderators.

[image: Close Dialog]

#### Show or hide the default off-topic close reasons

If, for some reason, you do not agree with the default close reasons, or you rarely need some of them, you can hide* them from the close dialog by deactivating them.

<sup>*: They will still show up in the close dialog if someone else has already chosen that reason for that particular question.</sup>

[image: Default Off-Topic Close Reasons]

#### Save your favorite custom off-topic close reasons

You no longer have to type your most commonly used close reasons over and over again. Simply save them once, and you can use them just the way you want.

[image: Custom Off-Topic Close Reasons]

### Requirements

- You need to have the "cast close and reopen votes" privilege (3000 reputation on graduated sites) in order to use the custom close reasons.
- You have to use a browser that supports `localStorage`.

### Download

- [Click here](http://laucheukhim.github.io/close-reason-editor/close-reason-editor.user.js) to install the latest version of the userscript
- [Click here](//github.com/laucheukhim/close-reason-editor/blob/gh-pages/close-reason-editor.user.js?) to view source
- [Click here](//stackapps.com/tags/script/info) for instructions on how to install userscripts

Comment: +1, awesome! I'd thought about writing a script to do something like this myself, but now I don't have to! :-) And the user interface you've got is incredibly polished.

Comment: Now make one where I can see instantly who is on-line (not in the Chat room) but in the Q&A.

Comment: I use this a lot now at PPCG. My Custom VTC is for incomplete challenges.

Comment: I assume this project has been abandoned? I've downloaded this quite some time ago and have always [encountered the same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cmc9.png) when attempting to add custom reasons.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I am sorry. I haven't been maintaining this script because I am not actively using the site these days. I will take a look at this if I do manage to find some time to debug it, but I can't promise anything. This script is open source however so other people can take over if they want.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I have fixed the problem and updated the script. StackExchange updated the topbar at some point and broke the script. Please click the download link for the latest version of the script and let me know if this works now. I am sorry to keep you waiting all this time. In the future, please post a bug report as an answer and I will try to fix it whenever possible.

Comment: You're awesome! Works perfectly now, thanks for the ping! :)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a problem, using Firefox ver. 38...

The adding of Tags to a new question initiates a scripting error and does not let me add tags.

If I turn off the close-reason-editor I am back to normal.

---

When I try to ask new question, and click on add tags, I get the Firefox to freeze with spinning beach ball followed by Error message.

This is the output:

```
Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. jquery.min.js:2:0
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:3:0
This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.[Learn More] qa.sockets.stackexchange.com
Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
m@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3:12414
m@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3:24740
.find@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3:26848
f</e.prototype.init@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:2:7841
f</e@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:2:6351
CloseReasonEditor.init/<@http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask:53:21
f.event.dispatch@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3:4299
f.event.add/i@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3:311
f.event.trigger@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3:3036
f.event.trigger@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3:2483
w@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:4:11465
.send/d@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:4:17218
 jquery.min.js:3:12413
```

[image]

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Can you open the JavaScript console and post the error message here? And what do you mean by "adding tags to a new question"? Are you on `/questions/ask`, `/posts/{id}/edit` or `/posts/{id}/edit-inline`?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue on Firefox 38 on a Mac on the "Ask Question" page. Please refer to [this post on how to open the JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525), and include relevant details in the bug report, e.g. the error message you see in the console, the URL of the page you where encounter the problem, a screenshot of the error, or any other information that may help explain the issue.

Comment: Will do, I removed the script since it was bugging me. Now I have to install it and report. Might be a while :)

Comment: @Antony OK, installed and running, nothing so far.

Comment: Thanks for the report. The bug has been fixed. Please update the userscript to the new version.

Comment: I had the same thing (haven't tried the updated script yet). Were you also getting a confirmation dialogue each time you attempted to post a  question or answer?

Answer (score 2):

This script caused me both the bug reported by [Buscar](https://stackapps.com/a/6349/17253) and [the one reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266425/203101) (I was asked to confirm leaving the page each time I posted a question or answer).

Removing the script solved both bugs and, since I don't really use it, I can live with that. I won't be following up on this but I thought it was worth reporting.

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: This is probably related to wmd.en.js being loaded twice. I have fixed this in the latest version of the script. Can you please update it to test it for me? I know you don't really use it, but making sure this is fixed properly would benefit those who do use the script.

Comment: @Antony I did try the new version you have in your answer before posting this. I still had the confirmation bug. Let me know if you update it again and I'll give it a go.

Comment: Are you using version 1.1.5? I just updated it an hour ago.

Comment: @Antony oh, sorry, I was looking at the time the OP was edited. OK, I'll try this tomorrow (no time now).